# Simple installable HTML website builder

Tags: web-development, html, web, html-editor

Looking for a simple, free, (low consumption) website builder I can install on my web host. The ones that are available with my web host are slow. Not looking for CMS (Wordpress, joomla, drupal) -- I only need 20-25 pages. It needs the capability of the user to be able to:

1. add pages
2. put content in
3. edit content

Nothing fancy, just html and run fast. Preferrably free.

Note/Reason: I have 1&1 web hosting and they discontinued the old, fast, website builder I was using and made a new, slower, website builder that destroys your website when you make 1 change to the css. I talked to customer support and they confirmed the page builder was taking up more resources.

Comment: As earlier, for a small site, fast to install and easy to manage, i proposed you to take a look at http://pluxml.org . http://wiki.pluxml.org/index.php?page=English it is french, but many users understand english on the forum (function/objects names uses english within the code for instance)

Comment: @GCyrillus this is hard for me to understand. Does it require I know how to use objects and functions?

Comment: for a lambda user , you only need to upload the unzipped file to server, first connection to site fires install.php ... install giving a name and a password. (install.php will not be call again). then load on administration, add an article (page), link it to a categorie. Or add a static page . this is it. Themes and plugin are to be copied/paste into specific folder and comes accessible. configuration(if needed can be made via administration) . for the function/objects, you 'll see them being called within the templates (themes), idems for plugins.

Comment: Why does it have to be installed on the webhost as opposed to used locally and have the results uploaded?

Comment: Yeah. If you can, just use a client-side text editor (or a programming IDE) , and upload your files with an FTP client. Some hosts may not allow such, though. Many simple IDEs for programming also have tools for web design.

Answer (score 0):

An option that might work for you is a WYSIWYG graphical website builder. There are two that I've used: BlueGriffon and Kompozer. They are similar in the sense that you do things using the graphical interface and they generate the HTML code. There are very useful tutorials for both. I developed a web page in a few hours by going thru the tutorial.

Comment: The question said "`Looking for a simple, free, (low consumption) website builder I can install on my web host`" - neither of those can be installed on a web site, AFAIK